# Why can't I autowire my JPA interface in Spring boot app?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am having problems with my Spring boot application (Sweet tooth app, a pastry selling web shop), I can't seem to load dependencies correctly... Here is the part of my setup I'm having problems with:
Main:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"controller", "repository", "service"})
public class SweetToothApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SweetToothApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Model class:

```java
@Entity
@Data
public class Category {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "category_id")
    
    private int id;
    private String name;   
}
```

Repository:

```java
@Repository
public interface CategoryRepo extends JpaRepository<Category, Integer>{}
```

Repo implementation:

```java
@Service
public class CategoryImplService {    
    @Autowired
    CategoryRepo categoryRepo;
    
    public List<Category> getAllCategories(){
        return categoryRepo.findAll();
    }
    
    public void addCategory(Category category){
        categoryRepo.save(category);
    }
    
}
```

Controller class:

```java
@Controller
public class AdminController {
    
    @Autowired
    CategoryImplService categoryImplService;    
    @GetMapping("/admin")
    public String adminHome(){
    
        return "adminHome";
    }// + other mappings...
```

When I run my app, this is what I get: Field categoryRepo in service.CategoryImplService required a bean of type 'repository.CategoryRepo' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
Been trying to fix this for a couple of days, nothing... I use Net Beans 15 IDE. This is my project structure:                                                             SourcePackages

```
       Package com.example.SweetTooth                                                                                                                              
                      SweetToothApp.java  (main class)                                                                                                                                         
       Package Controller                                                                                                                                                            
                     AdminController.java                                                                                                                               
        Package Model                                                                                                                                                                    
                    Category.java                                                                                                                                                         
        Package Repository                                                                                                                                                        
                    CategoryRepo.java (interface)                                                                                                                                            
        Package Service                                                                                                                                                             
                    CategoryImplService.java
```

Other sources
Package Templates... Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The fact that you already have `@ComponentScan` means you are doing it wrong. Your package structure is wrong. Move the packages you currently have under `com.example.SweetTooth`, so `com.example.SweetTooth.controller` instead of `controller` then remove the `@ComponentScan`. The `@Repository` on the Spring Data repository is useless as well it will only hurt your eyes. Don't use `@Data` for your entities (see https://deinum.biz/2019-02-13-Lombok-Data-Ojects-Arent-Entities/ for the why).

Comment: @M.Denium Thank you very much for your answer, yes, it seems my packages were all over the place, so spring couldn't find the right beans... Moved it to main solution package as you suggested and it now works perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can use ComponentScans avoid override SpringBootApplication default action:

```
@ComponentScans(
    @ComponentScan(basePackages={"controller", "repository", "service"})
)
```